# Deleting unpublished android application

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

I lost my keystore file for my application, so I can't upload a new apk to me application or even create a new application with the same package name.

So, I want to delete my application from Google play store. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe.. use the manual which you can find on Google

Comment: There's nothing in it regarding deleting my application.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Close.

Comment: Well, there's also no development or programming tag involved. And I guess my question is somehow related to programming, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have published an application with a package name, it's taken forever so there will be no point in deleting it because you cannot use the same package name again, but you can change your package name and upload it again with the new key

Answer (score 0):

Change to advanced, then select inactivate.

Comment: So, I can be able to upload my application again with the same package name after doing this?

Comment: No. Not as far as I know.

Comment: for next time, make sure to have a backup copy of your keystore.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I think I will just change my package name.